# Checkbox binding not working

Tags: wpf, binding, checkbox

I searched the forum and did everything as advised to create dependancy property and bind it to checkbox, but for some reason it doesn't bind.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=isLoop}" Content="" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,208,0,0" x:Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" />
```

C#

```
  public bool isLoop
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(isLoopProperty); }
        set { SetValue(isLoopProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty isLoopProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("isLoop", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

Comment: Does 'output' window give you a binding error?

Comment: What exactly means "It doesn't bind"?

Comment: @NestorArturo the variable isLoop doesn't react when i click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made some key mistakes in your sample.

First, you are not binding to an object that supports your "isLoop" property (unless "MainWindow" is a custom control that has that property).  Somewhere in that CheckBox's hierarchy, you need to set the DataContext to an object that supports it, or bind to an element that has that property.

Second, you should rarely, if ever, create a dependency property in your business object.  For business objects, follow the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern.  Typically, you should create dependency properties in visual UI elements, such as custom controls in order to be able to bind data to them (a target, not the source).

So, to fix your problem, you should probably create an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, create an IsLoop property that throws the NotifyPropertyChanged event in the setter, and set this object as the DataContext to the CheckBox's parent container (or further up the hierarchy if appropriate).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the Window itself. Do you mean to do that? Unless your code example is in the code behind then the binding will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an `ElementName` binding, I am guessing you are binding to a UI element. The problem is, none of the default UI elements come with a property called `isLoop`, so your binding is invalid.

There are a few things you can try.

If your `isLoop` property is part of the object named MainWindow's `DataContext`, change your binding to `DataContext.isLoop`

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=DataContext.isLoop}" ... />
```

If `isLoop` is actually a property on a custom class called `MainWindow`, such as your dependency property implies, verify that the object named `MainWindow` is actually of type `MainWindow`

```
<local:MainWindow x:Name="MainWindow" />
```

And if neither of those work, post your full XAML (particularly the part named `MainWindow`), the code for the class `MainWindow`, and the code that ties the `MainWindow` class object with the XAML UI.

Answer (score 0):

The isLoop won't trigger when the checkbox is clicked.  That is simply for accessing the depency property in code.  You should add a PropertyCallback function and register that in the  metadata.